# Docker CE installation on Ubuntu 16.04 crashes network

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, docker, amazon-ec2

I am trying to install docker-ce 17.09 on ubuntu 16.04 instance on AWS. The instance is behind the company VPC and the security group assigned allows all TCP & UDP traffics.
However, the whole network crashed and I lost SSH connection to my instance when the installation of Docker reached:

```
Setting up docker-ce (17.09.0~ce-0~ubuntu) ...
Connection reset by ... port 22
```

Is that because of the VPC settings? Or any other reason?

**Updated**

As I'm not able to change the existing VPC. I decided not to use Ubuntu instance but amazon AMI instead.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your VPC and docker subnets are conflicting.  Which means you can either redo your VPC to use a different subnet, or you can change the docker bridge subnet:  https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/custom-docker0/

Comment: Would you please give a bit more details like in what way they are conflicting, is it the IP address in "daemon.json" conflicting with the VPC subnet ip address? I don't have much experience configuring VPN network. I'm not able to modify "daemon.json" as I lost connection during the Docker installation. I might have to go for changing VPC settings. Should I just choose a different VPC subnet when I launch a new EC2 instance?

Comment: I'm not sure which it would actually be, but it could be either the bridge subnet or the docker0 subnet, BIP or CIDR in the daemon.json.   More than likely it's trying to use a subnet that your VPC is using, so there is a conflict.   Personally I haven't ran into this before, so this is an educated guess.   If your network isn't too complex, then yes you can just create a new VPC with a different subnet, maybe just do one as a test with a single instance to see if that resolves it.